# How to create a virtual systemd service to stop/start several instances together?

Tags: ubuntu, systemd

I plan to host several instances of the same web app for customers using `systemd`.  I would like to be able to `stop` and `start` each customer instance using `systemd`, as well as treating the whole collection of customer instances as a single service that can be stopped and started together.

`systemd` seems to provide the building blocks I need using `PartOf`, and template unit files, but went I stop the parent service, the child customer service is not stopped. How can I make this work with systemd? Here's what I have so far.

The parent unit file, `app.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=App Web Service

[Service]
# Don't run as a deamon (because we've got nothing to do directly)
Type=oneshot
# Just print something, because ExecStart is required
ExecStart=/bin/echo "App Service exists only to collectively start and stop App instances"
# Keep running after Exit start finished, because we want the instances that depend on this to keep running
RemainAfterExit=yes
StandardOutput=journal
```

A unit template file named `app@.service`, used to create customer instances:

```
[Unit]
Description=%I Instance of App Web Service

[Service]
PartOf=app.service
ExecStart=/home/mark/bin/app-poc.sh %i
StandardOutput=journal
```

My `app-poc.sh` script (Proof of concept that just prints to log file in a loop):

```
#!/bin/bash
# Just a temporary code to fake a full daemon.
while :
do
  echo "The App PoC loop for $@"
  sleep 2;
done
```

For the proof of concept, I've got the systemd unit files in `~/.config/systemd/user`.

I then start up the parent and an instance based on the template (after `systemctl --user daemon-reload` ):

```
systemctl --user start app
systemctl --user start app@customer.service
```

From using `journalctl -f` I can see that both started and that the customer instance continues to run. Now I I expect shutting down the parent will stop the child (because I used [`PartOf`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#PartOf=)), but it doesn't. Also, starting the parent isn't starting the child as expected either.

```
systemctl --user stop app
```

Thanks!

(I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 with systemd 229).

Comment: "PartOf= Configures dependencies similar to Requires=, but limited to stopping and restarting of units." If you want starting to work, don't you need to use `Requires=` instead?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to move the line

```
PartOf=app.service
```

out of `[Service]` and into the `[Unit]` section, and add to the `[Unit]` of `app.service` the list of customers to start, eg

```
Wants=app@customer1.service app@customer2.service
```

or as sourcejedi said in the comments, `Requires=` the same thing. You can keep the `PartOf` to stop services you start by hand that are not in the above list, like `systemctl --user start app@customer3.service`.

Comment: I confirmed you were right about `PartOf`. Thanks. I'm going to handle the "Wants" through a symlink, which becomes the single action I need to take to activate a new customer with systemd. For my test case: ` ln -s /home/mark/.config/systemd/user/app@.service /home/mark/.config/systemd/user/app.service.wants/unity@foo.service`

Answer (score 18):

I learned that this what systemd "Target Units" are for. By using a Target Unit, I get the benefits I want without needing to create the fake `[Service]` section I had above. A working example "Target Unit" file looks like this:

```
# named like app.target
[Unit]
Description=App Web Service

# This collection of apps should be started at boot time.
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then each customer instance should include `PartOf` in the `[Unit]` section (as pointed out by @meuh), and should also have an `[Install]` section so that `enable` and `disable` will work on the specific service:

```
# In a file name like app@.service
[Unit]
Description=%I Instance of App Web Service
PartOf=app.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/mark/bin/app-poc.sh %i
Restart=on-failure
StandardOutput=journal

# When the service runs globally, make it run as a particular user for added security
#User=myapp
#Group=myapp

# When systemctl enable is used, make this start when the App service starts
[Install]
WantedBy=app.target
```

To bring up the customer instance and have it start when the target is started, this one-time enable command is used:

```
 systemctl enable app
```

Now at this point I can use `stop` and `start` on `app@customer` to for a specific instance, or I can use `start app` and `stop app` to stop all the apps together.

Comment: How about status?

I can't find a simple way to get a status of all services that App wanted. I know how I can script that, but ...

Comment: Status is easy. If you your apps instances are named like `app@cust1`, `app@cust2`, use `systemctl status 'app@*'`. The wildcard notation will give you status information for all instances together.

Comment: I mean like getting the status of apps in that target group without listing all that are part of it, wild cards or not, preferably using that group name and not even caring what it's made of.

Comment: @TommiKyntola I'm not sure how what you are asking for is different. `systemctl status `app@*` *does* give you the status of apps in the `app` target group, it *does* use the target group name and it *doesn't* require you to list the specific instance names.

Comment: Well, ours have been named more like `foo@*, bar, xxx@*, zzz` that are all partOf `sometarget`, the template ids are just numbers indicating an instance number, but not all services have that. And sometimes we add new services to that group.

Thus, what I'd like to just `systemctl status sometarget`.

Granted, what we could do is rename them `sometarget@foo1` etc, but I that seems clumsy and unnecessary.

Comment: Create a tiny bash script `sometarget-status` and add a few lines to it: `systemctl status 'foo@*'\nsystemctl status bar\n systemctl status 'xxx@*'\nsystemctl status zzz`

Comment: It's not that simple. To which packet would that script belong to? It would have to be modified every time a new component is added. Forget that and deployment/maintenance goes haywire.

What I'd obviously want is to just add a new packet with partOf setting indicating it's presence in that group and _not_ then modify some script lingering about. And then stop and start of that target works like before. This works, but status seems to fall out of that scope. I can't even find a way to get a listing of units that are runtime present in a target.

This use case is not covered by systemd.

Comment: @TommiKyntola Here's a bash one-liner that you don't need to update as the target dependencies change: `systemctl status $(systemctl  list-dependencies --plain otp.target)`

Comment: @TommiKyntola I agree that `systemd` could improve the usability here. I've [opened a feature request](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/9273) to suggest improved status for targets.

Comment: Note: you should use systemd v235 or newer if need reload ability for *target*-units.